# Windows 11 Notepad has wide margin on left and top

Tags: windows-11, notepad

After upgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 11 (version 22H2) I noticed that Notepad has quite a wide margin on the left and top (see screenshot below, comparing Windows 7, 10 and 11).

From screenshots on the web I see this is the default in Windows 11 (IOW: most screenshots of Notepad in Windows 11 have this wide margin), but hope there is some setting to reduce the margin.

Note: there are older threads on internet asking about the margin where the following solutions are proposed:

- change the Margins settings in Page Set -> they only affect printing, not on screen presentation
- change the font -> does not have any effect, tried a few, including the ones from Windows 7 and 10 as in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Try repairing and resetting Notepad in Settings apps.  Then restart and test. I do not see an abnormal margin in Windows 11 Notepad here. I am quite sure what you see is normal for Windows 11

Comment: The margin likely is just a visual representation and won’t appear on paper.  Regardless, if there is no option to remove it, then you’ll have to find a different application

Comment: I also use Ultra Edit and included that possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Windows 11 to much older versions.

Windows 11 Notepad as you see is totally normal. All 3 Windows 11 Pro machines.

Text does not touch or get close to the left side or top in Windows 11 with Notepad. You cannot remove this space.

See my own screen shot.

[image: Win 11 Notepad]

.

If you just do not want that space, I also Ultra Edit and it does not have such a margin. So consider an alternative.

[image: Ultra Edit]

Comment: "You are comparing Windows 11 to much older versions."
I compare Windows 11 22H2 to Windows 10 21H2, that is a one year of difference.

Comment: Once screen says Windows 7.  But even with Windows 10 - Windows 11 Notepad is different. What I showed is true for Notepad on Windows 11 today.